# AJAX unable to load correctly unless i refresh the page

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

I am developing a web page( to which i am relatively new to) and am coming into trouble. I have two divs in my HTML page which are being refreshed with AJAX. The problem is that the content loading is quite temperamental unless i refresh the page myself or use a timed meta data refresh which i want to avoid using. The page works fine when i am accessing my server over LAN but occurs when i am accessing it through the web, here is the parts effected

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var jsonData = $.ajax({
      url: "gg.php",
      dataType:"json",
      async: false
                        }).responseText;
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, {width: 800, height: 480});};setInterval(drawChart,1000);
    </script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
setInterval(function() {
$('#minmax_layout').load('minmax.php');
}, 1000);
});
</script>

<div id="chart_div"></div>
<div id="minmax_layout"></div>
```

Any help on this issue will be much apprciated

Answer (score 0):

I can see 2 ajax call on a page one is

```
drawChart()
```

and another one is

`$('#minmax_layout').load('minmax.php')`.

and you second ajax call is called every second continuously. could cause that issue. increase the time to slow down so that it gets response from server properly and display. If response from server delays next call will be triggered.

Also consider using asyc call to avoid issues.